# $.parseJSON() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to parse some data from my ERP platform (API written in C#).
When I try to parse the info contained in data, I get an undefined result. 
I've been looking for some answers and I even could figure out an alternative way to do it, with this:

```
for(var  i in data){

      top[i] = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data[i]));
```

But I'd like to know why this JSON parse isn't working since I'm doing as demanded.

My web app API is written in Ruby on Rails, FYI

Best regards,

**.js file(home.js)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#artigos-container').html(botao_load);

    var id_categoria = $("#titulo-categoria").attr('data-id-categoria');
    console.log("ID CATEGORIA : " + id_categoria);
    var url_categoria = base_url_primavera + '/categorias/'+id_categoria;

    /*var id_subcategoria = null;
    var url_subcategoria = null;
    var subcategoria = $("#titulo-subcategoria");
    if(subcategoria.length){
        is_subcategoria = true;
        id_subcategoria = subcategoria.attr('data-id-subcategoria');
        url_subcategoria = base_url_primavera + '/categorias/'+id_categoria+'/subcategoria/' + id_subcategoria;
    }*/

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url_categoria,
        error: function (err) {
            console.log("error fetching category");
            $("#titulo-categoria").html('erro');
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var categoria_temp = $.parseJSON(data);
            var desc_categoria = categoria_temp.DescCategoria;
            console.log(desc_categoria);
            $("#titulo-categoria").html(desc_categoria);
        }
    })
});
```

The **data** variable log is

```
{"CodCategoria":"H01","DescCategoria":"Computadores","numExemplaresCategoria":0}
```

Comment: What **exactly** is the error you get?

Comment: The result of that parse is undefined so the following errors I get are about it. The main question is why is that parse returning null or undefined.

Comment: `$.parseJSON` has been deprecated, you should use the built-in `JSON.parse()`

Comment: Since you wrote `dataType: 'json'`, jQuery will automatically parse the JSON response, and sets `data` to the result. So when you call `$.parseJSON(data)` yourself, `data` is not a JSON string.

Comment: Are suggesting `var categoria_temp = $.JSON.parse(data);` instead of what I got? Cause it returns the same, undefined.

Comment: I'm suggesting `var categoria_temp = data;`, since `data` is already parsed.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have already mentioned `dataType: 'json'`, jQuery will already parse the data. So you don't need to parse again.

So change this line `var categoria_temp = $.parseJSON(data);` to,

```
var categoria_temp = data;
```

Also when you do `for..in` as below, the value in `data[i]` is not a valid `json` to parse.

```
for(var  i in data){

      top[i] = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data[i]));
```